# How to set a Datasource explicitly in yml file and change it when I go for personalization?

Tags: jss

I'm using Jss react. I want to pass a datasource to a component which is coming from a different location (not from component itself or sitecore context). I want to use personalization so the datasource of the component can be changed depending on user type.

Lets say I have a product page, which will use different product type depending on user preference.

Is there a way to specify datasource in yml file so it can work in disconnected mode and as well as connected and integrated modes.
something like this->

```
jss-main:
    - componentName: Product
      dataSource: Product5
      fields:
```

Or, is there any other way of doing it which can work in all the modes and can be personalized?

Regards,